# Difficulties with creating a function to delete data from the database

Tags: php, laravel, database-table, laravel-datatables

I created a button in the table to implement the function of deleting data on the site, I did everything according to the video tutorial and after I did everything refreshing the page I got an error:

Undefined variable: value (View: /home/vagrant/code/bacon/resources/views/business.blade.php)

(I still attached a screenshot of the error) https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nLEX.png

My Controller "BusinessController.php":

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
use \App\Models\Business;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BusinessController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $business = \App\Models\Business::all();
        return view('business', compact('business'));
    }

    public function createbusiness()
    {
        return view('/createbusiness');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('business.create');
    }

    function delete($idd)
    {
        DB::table('business')->where('idd',$idd)->delete();
        return redirect ('/business');
    }

    public  function store()
    {
        $business = new Business();
        $business->idd = request('idd');
        $business->name = request('name');
        $business->mail = request('mail');
        $business->website = request('website');
        $business->save();
        return redirect('/business');
    }
}
```

My route "web.php":

```php
<?php

    use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Web Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
    |
    */

    Route::get('/welcome', 'App\Http\Controllers\MainController@welcome');
    Route::get('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\MainController@users');
    Route::get('/business', 'App\Http\Controllers\BusinessController@index');
    Route::post('/business', 'App\Http\Controllers\BusinessController@store');
    Route::get('/projects', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@index');
    Route::post('/projects', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@store');
    Route::get('/projects/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@create');
    Route::get('/business/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\BusinessController@createbusiness');
    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/delete/{idd}','App\Http\Controllers\BusinessController@delete');
    Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

My view "business.blade.php":

```php
@extends('layouts.layout')
@section('title')Бізнес@endsection
@section ('main_content')
    <h1>Бизнес</h1>
    <p>
    <table class="table table-dark">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Mail</th>
                <th scope="col">Website</th>
                <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                <th scope="col">Delete</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($business as $singleBusiness)
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{ $singleBusiness->idd}}</th>
                    <td>{{ $singleBusiness->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $singleBusiness->mail}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $singleBusiness->website}}</td>
                        <td><a href="/delete/{{ $value->idd }}">
       <button class="btn btn-danger btn-delete">Delete</button></a></td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <a class="col-4 btn btn-outline-warning mr-3" href="/business/create">Додати Бізнес</a>
        </p>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `<td><a href="/delete/{{ $value->idd }}">` to `<td><a href="/delete/{{ $singleBusiness->idd }}">`

Comment: but there was another error(:

Class 'App \ Http \ Controllers \ DB' not found

Comment: It problem with my controller

Comment: Use like this \DB::

Comment: Works, thank you very much again, I will confirm now

Answer (score 0):

Change route Methid Get method to Post Method!

`Route::post('/delete/{idd}','App\Http\Controllers\BusinessController@delete')->name('Delete');

```
<Form action="{{ route( 'Delete', $singleBusiness->id) }}" method="POST" >
    @csrf  
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-delete">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't have a variable "id"